# Select a <select> option using jQuery in a way that triggers any change handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, google-translate

I'm using Google Translate's dropdown menu to translate a site, but this doesn't persist across pages, so I'm trying to manually select the needed option on page load to make it persistent.

However, just using `$('#google_translate_element select').val('es');` doesn't trigger the event that actually translates the page. I can't figure out how to manipulate this  programmatically in a way that actually triggers the onchange event.

I've also tried:

```
$('#google_translate_element select option[value=es]').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
```

and

```
$('#google_translate_element select').val('es').trigger('change');
```

No luck. Any ideas?

For the record, here's the HTML I'm working with (which is output by Google Translate's script)

```
<div id="google_translate_element">
  <div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" style="">
    <div id=":1.targetLanguage" style="display: inline; ">
      <select class="goog-te-combo">
        <option value="">Select Language
        </option>
        <option value="es">Spanish
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found http://translateth.is/ and ended up using that instead of this nonsense. It persists across page loads by default and still uses Google Translate's API.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me ... code it be that the event is not "change" but rather "click".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$('#google_translate_element select').bind('change', function(){alert('changed');});
That registers handler for onchange event.